# Portable ctypes.c_char_p for python 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python, ctypes

From the ctypes documentation of [python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes), we have:

```
>>> printf("String '%s', Int %d, Double %f\n", "Hi", 10, 2.2)
```

And from the ctypes documentation of [python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes), we have:

```
>>> printf(b"String '%s', Int %d, Double %f\n", b"Hi", 10, 2.2)
```

So in one case the argtypes for `c_char_p` requires a `str` as input, while in the second case it requires `bytes`. How should I write my function to handle both python 2.x and python 3.x ?

Typical scenario is:

```
my_c_func.argtypes = [ c_char_p ]
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  filename = sys.argv[1];
  my_c_func( filename )
```

Comment: My quick check suggest that in python 2 `b'abc'` is the same as `'abc'`.

Comment: The main thing is to ensure you don't get a unicode string both p2 and p3 work the same way if it's a bytes variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those types are equivalent. In C strings are arrays or pointers to the char type (each char represented by one byte). In python 3 the closest data type is `bytes`. Strings in python 3 are encoded using UTF-8, so each char is not guaranteed to be exactly one byte. Whereas, in python 2 strings are typically encoded using Latin-1 (depends on your locale I believe) -- one char, one byte.

To write code that works regardless of interpreter version you should just write `b"your string"`. This creates a `str` object in python 2 and a `bytes` object in python 3. Conversely to guarantee a unicode string use `u"your string"`. This creates a `unicode` object in python 2 and a `str` object in python 3.

Comment: The default encoding in Python 2 is ASCII, not Latin-1, but typically byte strings will be in the filesystem or locale encoding. Strings in Python 3 are not encoded. You probably mean the default encoding used for source code and `str.encode` is UTF-8 in Python 3, but of course you can use whatever encoding you want. The OP's `sys.argv` example will use the filesystem encoding in Python 2 and a unicode string in Python 3. These issues aren't particular to ctypes. The [six module](http://pythonhosted.org/six) can help ease the pain of supporting 2.x and 3.x from a common code base.